# javascript RegExp validate url expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

I have already found many posts on this subject, however no post handles my specific issue.

This is the regex that I use (found on this website) :

```
function validateUrl(value){
        return /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/i.test(value);
}
```

This validates my url correct till up to the following point:

> mydomain.tld/mypage/this'go(es{wro[ng

My function returns true, even when there are not-allowed characters like:
 `'` or `"` or `(` or `)` or `[` or `]` or `{` or `}`

I don't understand why this is allowed. I have this: `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]`
Should return '`false`' in my opinion...

Comment: I haven't looked at it closely, but my initial guess is that it's only matching a part of the input, but regex still considers a partial a match.  To force it to check the whole input string, you need to use the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @StevenDoggart that sounds like an answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @Thomas True, but I didn't want to take the time to ensure that my hunch was correct.  I'm happy enough to let Atif get the points if that really is the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex almost works. In the string `mydomain.tld/mypage/this'go(es{wro[ng` it matches `mydomain.tld/mypage/this`. As you didn't put anchors in both ends, it does match ([partially](https://regex101.com/r/iW1iO7/1)).

Just change it to:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)$
^                                                                        ^
```

See <kbd>[LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/iW1iO7/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function validateUrl(value){
        return /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/.test(value);
}
```

Comment: Explaining why the original version doesn't work as expected would be great, so that the OP understands the issue.